# Can an auto-scaled GAE Instance commit suicide?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I occasionally get an instance in which something goes wrong with my imports.  While I work to find the root cause, is it possible to programmatically tell GAE that this instance is unstable and have it terminated?

In my case, 'unstable' means that every request to the affected instance which requires certain imports will exception.

This module happens to run background processing, so I can cope if all concurrent requests are killed off.  It would be nicer to just stop new requests and shut down when the current ones were over, but my priority is to avoid thousands of failed requests over the lifetime of the instance.

(The problem seems to be marked by a DeadlineExceededError (60s timeout) on the first request which requires those imports, from which I guess that something is left part-imported.  I haven't figure out why these rare few take so long.)

This is an auto-scaled python 2.7 instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "this instance is unstable"? All instances the same. Also, if you use multi-threading, you are going to kill all other user requests that are being processed by this instance.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, I have added more detail on my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that "instance" equals your module. In that case, yes, you may kill it, if you would assign a specific combination module/version to the module you want to kill, you should be able to terminate with the stop_version method.

Here's the API for Python modules. Look for your language if different.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/functions

Comment: Unfortunately the `stop_version` function is not applicable to auto scaled modules.  "Stop all instances for a given version of a module. Valid only for manual or basic scaled modules."